# Alphanumeric to numeric only

Tags: c#, .net

Looking for fast/efficient ways to convert an alphanumeric to a number only string

e.g.   +123-456/7890 becomes 1234567890 etc.

the existing code is

```
foreach(char c in str.ToCharArray() )
  if ( char.IsDigit(c) ) stringBuilder.Append(c);

return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: what are you actually after?... new ideas (eg. use regex), or benchmarks? why are you asking this question - just for info, or is there a real-world scenario?

Comment: I don't think your approach is slow.. if measure in speed, should be much faster than regex. The only improvement I can imagine is to replace with Linq, but not in speed, only cleaner code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361986/how-get-integer-only-and-remove-all-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ImranRizvi, this isn't duplicate because he didn't ask for "How to" he asked "Faster than this".

Comment: oh ok, you are right,check I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ Solution:

```
return new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Not sure if it's more efficient; at-least it's not regex!

Answer (score 4):

```
string str="+123-456/7890";
long onlyNumbers= Convert.ToInt64(Regex.Replace(str, @"\D", ""));
```

Comment: @Kumar: And if your number goes beyond `Int32.MaxValue = 2147483647`, use Convert.ToInt64(...); which can give you results till `Int64.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807`

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, it's really not as faster, but it's more readable and comfortable to use regexes for me.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Regex is faster among all the answers given here. Please see my answer for the clarification.

Comment: @ChuckNorris: Regex is faster among all the answers given here. Please see my answer for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes RegEx is faster among others , you can make the comparison even more faster using **RegexOptions.Compiled** to match the negative/positive cases and reside them apart (if such strings can exists)

e.g.

```
Regex numberOnlyRegEx = new Regex(@"[^0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

if (!numberOnlyRegEx.IsMatch(str))
  return 0; //default value;

return Convert.ToInt32(numberOnlyRegEx .Replace(str, "[^0-9]+", ""));
```

Comment: I tested it using Ideone, which gives completely reverse results and now the question would be what to trust VS-IDE or Ideone ?

Comment: @Marshal thats strange, I believe more on VS-IDE results as it is on your local machine , but can't say so early.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another solution found

```
string justNumbers = new String(text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(justNumbers);
```

Comment: This process is much slower (4 ms) compared to Regex comparisons (1 ms). Although it may not harm too much to the application, (it was just a small 'research')

Answer (score 1):

After seeing many answers which try not to use Regex in this situation, I would like to say actually Regex works much faster in this particular case. I tried calculating time taken for execution using [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773473/any-tool-that-says-how-long-each-method-takes-to-run/3773538#3773538)

Method suggested by

- **Imran Rizvi** takes **1291 Ticks** [Ideone says time: 0.06s memory: 36992 kB](http://ideone.com/0t29Z)
- **Chuck Norris** takes **1336 Ticks** [Ideone says time: 0.06s    memory: 37080 kB](http://ideone.com/uTCHt)
- **Andy** takes **12866 Ticks** [Ideone says time: 0.04s    memory: 36888 kB](http://ideone.com/1oPPW)
- **COLD TOLD** takes **18855 Ticks**; [time: 0.03s memory: 36904 kB](http://ideone.com/l8idA)

**Edit:** These give two completely opposite outputs, i don't know if we should completely trust Ideone than Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Marshal, put your code in [IDEone](http://ideone.com/tH4O4), currently I don't have anything to test, but this place can be acceptable for both of us.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Okay I will try to find that too :)

Comment: Marshal, just type ideone.com then post your code within it, and left the related link here.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri: I tested it using Ideone, which gives result as you expected, but than the question would be what to trust VS-IDE or Ideone ?

Comment: There is not much difference, would you show me your link? I think your test case is not good and we should change it a little.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Links are posted in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10691/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-marshal)

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are only running the test once (as your snippet implies) you may be seeing the affects of JIT compiler in these times.